# Adding to a hashmap

Tags: hashmap

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Point> fillCellsCreatures = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      Creature cre = new Creature();
      cre.x = ((int)(Math.random() * ((30 - 10) +1)));
      cre.y = ((int)(Math.random() * ((30 - 10) +1)));
      cre.energy_level = 10;
      //fillCellsCreatures.add(new Point(cre.x, cre.y));
      fillCellsCreatures.put(cre.energy_level, new Point(cre.x, cre.y));
    }
```

The code above is me trying to add to a hashmap that contains an int as the key and a Point as the value. When i add to the hashmap via the for loop it appears i am constantly rewriting over the same position and rather not moving to the next position to add the new value. Could someone please help clarify what i am doing wrong and point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: Each time you have used same key (cre.energy_level = 10;). Since always replace the old one with new one.

Comment: Cheers Geeth. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change use following code,

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Point> fillCellsCreatures = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      Creature cre = new Creature();
      cre.x = ((int)(Math.random() * ((30 - 10) +1)));
      cre.y = ((int)(Math.random() * ((30 - 10) +1)));
      cre.energy_level = 10 * i+1;
      //fillCellsCreatures.add(new Point(cre.x, cre.y));
      fillCellsCreatures.put(cre.energy_level, new Point(cre.x, cre.y));
    }
```